# How to create Shopify webhook for customer login?

Tags: shopify, webhooks, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-storefront-api

I am trying to make my custom application to listen for webhooks from Shopify.

I need to receive customer ID on customer login. Unfortunately Shopify don't have built in functionality.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: There is a kind of hacky way to do it, and there we need to call our endpoint manually, if you are comfortable then i can share.

Comment: @HardikSatasiya what do you mean manually? please share if you have a solution

Comment: I have added an answer, if you need help with implementation, please let me know 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no webhook for customer login natively available. we can manually trigger web-hook by our custom logic.

> Put this JS in your `theme.liquid` file

```js
<script>
  let loginWebhook = false;  
  {% if customer != nil %}
    if(!window.localStorage.getItem('logged')) {
      loginWebhook = true;  
    }
  {% else %}
    window.localStorage.removeItem('logged')
  {% endif %}
</script>
```

> Put this JS in your `main-account.liquid` file

```js
<script>
  if(loginWebhook) {
    window.localStorage.setItem('logged', 1);
    console.log('CALL endpoint of webhook', '{{- customer.email -}}');
    // Make a fetch request here and call the webhook endpoint
    // Manually call webhook
    /*
    const webhookURL = 'http://webhookurl.com/log-login';
    const webhookData = {
      'email': '{{- customer.email -}}',
      // HERE add other data which is needed in webhook
      // customer id etc..
    };
    fetch(webhookURL, {
      method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(webhookData),
    });
    */
  }
</script>
```

#### Logic

when the `customer` object is available on the page, we check if we have already called the `webhook` or not.

1. if we did not call webhook we set `loginWebhook to true`
2. now the customer will `land on the` account page` after login every time
3. here we check `loginWebhook` if it's `true` we call webhook
4. we set the localStorage value `logged` to `1` so next time we don't call the webhook

Now user will surf the site, and all that time we will not call the webhook as we already called it and store info into localStorage.

If the customer will `logout` then we remove the `logged` value from localStorage.

So, Now next time when a user logs in we will again call `webhook` and we repeat from the top.

#### Implementation in live-action [Shopify Customer Login Webhook]

[image: Shopify Customer Login Webhook]

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: you are most welcome 